# Actionscript 3 Multiple sounds playing at the same time when accessing different movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I am at the moment trying to create an interactive movie, structured so that each keyframe in the timeline contains a movieclip navigated to using buttons inside the movieclips, with the appropriate code inside the main timeline.

The problem right now is that when you access the movieclip inside frame 3, the sound from frame 2 also plays simultaneously. After doing some research i found that this appears to be a bug with flash itself, and most of the time is dealt with using SoundMixer.stopAll();. Sadly, i have no idea how to use it to kill the sound from frame 2 when only frame 3 is accessed.

I know that when accessing frame 2 instead, only frame 2 is played, which should mean that flash basically goes through all frames on the way to the frame you are supposed to go to.

This is the limited code i am using at the moment:

Frame 1:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

stop();
var soundVar:int = 0;

var Choice1F:SimpleButton;
var Choice1R:SimpleButton;

this.Val1.Choice1F.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{buttonHandler(me, 2)});
this.Val1.Choice1R.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{buttonHandler(me, 3)});

function buttonHandler(e:MouseEvent, Value:int): void{
SoundMixer.stopAll();
soundVar = Value;
this.gotoAndPlay(Value);
}
```

Frame 2:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

stop();

if(soundVar == 3){
SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

Frame 3 simply contains a stop(); statement. The code in frame 2 was a futile attempt from me to make it kill the sound on its way to frame 3. Hopefully, you guys can think of a better solution, if one even exists.

Comment: PS: stop() is a function

Answer (score 1):

The correct structure of the project assumes that you control the playback of music and sounds with a special instance of custom class. And timeline you use only gave him command when and what to do.
One `SoundChannel` and couple of `Sound`'s will do the trick.

You could use this one

```
package src.utils{
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    public dynamic class BackgroundMusicPlayer extends Object{
        public var playlist;
        public var sndChannel;
        private var ID;
        public function BackgroundMusicPlayer(srcList:Array){
            playlist=[];
            for(var i=0;i<srcList.length;i++){
                var src= new URLRequest(srcList[i]);
                var newSound = new Sound(src);
                playlist.push(newSound);
            }
        }
        public function playMusic(id){
            if (sndChannel!=undefined) {
                sndChannel.stop();
            }
            sndChannel = playlist[id].play();
            ID=id;
            sndChannel.addEventListener("soundComplete",replayListener);
        }
        public function replayListener(e){
            sndChannel = playlist[ID].play();
        }
    }
}
```

import class to you timeline, create instance passing him files list

```
var musicPlayer = new BackgroundMusicPlayer("music1.mp3","music2.mp3");
```

And then you want start some sound, call

```
musicPlayer.playMusic(0);
```

If you want use imported to project sounds, just share them to actionscript, give them class names and slightly modify given class constructor

```
public function BackgroundMusicPlayer(srcList:Array){
    playlist=[];
    for(var i=0;i<srcList.length;i++){
         playlist.push(srcList[i]);
    }
}
```

So your instance creation now should be

```
var musicPlayer = new BackgroundMusicPlayer(new MySound1(),new MySound2());
```

Comment: The movieclips currently in use feature both video and audio content, which means that the audio is internal and, as far as i know, this can't be accessed through normal means. Is there any way to remove the sound from frame two without touching the sound from frame 1 when both overlap? Otherwise i simply have to export the audio from the original project.

Comment: What do you mean by can't be accessed? If sound imported in fla-project, then it inside Library and added in frame using property inspector. Just remove it from frame, add identifier in library and leave `musicPlayer.playMusic(0);` instead. Removing sound from frames then they added in IDE is not that simple because it work of garbage collector and you should find all references to it.

Comment: The movieclips are imported in FLV files, not FLA. That's sort of the problem, and that's why i suggested exporting the audio from the original project to work with.

Comment: FLV is Flash Video File (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video), how for god sakes you could import MovieClip, which is ActionScript class into it?)

Comment: By embedding the FLV into an SWF, a viable option when importing files into flash.

Comment: Embedding FLV in SWF is not embedding MovieClip in FLV (which is impossible)

Comment: Well, the files in question are FLV embedded into SWF files then. Does that clear things up about how to do this? I'll try to be more clear about my problems next time.

Comment: If you embed flv file in timeline, then sound they contain will only can be heard if you flv still on stage somehow. Is it so? Do you need preserve video from other frame at another but mute his sound? Or there is separated video files you wanna observe but somehow then you move to another one, you still hear first one sound?